# OSX 10.6.4 Terminal Problems

Tags: macos, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Terminal Problems OSX 10.6.4](https://superuser.com/questions/195776/terminal-problems-osx-10-6-4)

I commonly have long terminal commands and whenever I try to use the command history (by pressing the up-arrow) the text formatting becomes all garbled and the cursor appears in the wrong place.  At this point editing the command becomes impossible and the actual position of the cursor is not properly represented on the screen.

If I resize the terminal window to allows the entire command to fit on one line then the formatting gets corrected but sometimes I don't have enough screen real estate to accomplish this.  Any ideas?

[image]
(This is what happens when I have a command longer than one line, it overwrites the prompt instead of returning)

[image]
(This is the result of pressing the up-arrow)

Comment: A lot could probably be accomplished by wrapping some of the longer ones in shell scripts. Jus' sayin'.

Comment: I get the same problem with Putty terminal emulator. Maybe It's a unix shell bug.

Comment: superuser.com maybe?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/195776/terminal-problems-osx-10-6-4